# This method should invert the numbers in the ArrayList

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Metodo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList();
        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(4);
        a.add(5);
        Metodo.inverte(a);
        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void inverte(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> other = new ArrayList();
        other = a;
        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
            a.set(i, other.get(other.size()-i-1));
        }
    }
}
```

This method should ivert the numbers in the ArrayList so it should print "5 4 3 2 1" but it prints "5 4 3 4 5" instead. Why?

Answer (score 5):

```
other = a;
```

does **not** create a copy of the original `List`.

Both `a` and `other` reference the same `List` object, so when you call `a.set(0,other.get(other.size()-1)`, you lose the original value of `other.get(0)`.

You should use:

```
ArrayList<Integer> other = new ArrayList<>(a);
```

to create a copy of the original `List` and remove `other = a;`

Answer (score 2):

Eran already answered this question, but a simple note here. that you can reverse ArrayList using:

```
Collections.reverse(arrayList)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the items of `a` into `other` in the **reverse order** and `return` the result:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> inverte(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> other = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = a.size() - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        other.add(a.get(i));
    }
    return other;
}
```

So you do:

```
a = Metodo.inverte(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in answers made, you can learn two things about your programing language:

1. What is the difference between a copy and a reference? See @Eran's answer

   If you change the order of the items in a list when you make a loop on it, you will encounter problems.
2. How standard libraries and built-in types can help you? See @Mahmoud Hanafy's answer

   You need to spend time to know what the language and its ecosystem can afford to you. For instance, it is very important you understand that `reverse` a collection is something very common, and on every new line you have to ask you: how other developers handle this.